# How to prevent one update panel from affecting another c# asp

Tags: c#, webforms, updatepanel

My problem is the following, when I first use the droplist of the first updatepanel to function correctly it shows me the label and textbox that are hidden, everything works fine.

But, when I use first the dropProvince, canton or district, they implement the method

```
protected void 
droplistTipoIdentificacionDatosPropietario_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs and )
{
    MessageBox.Show ("hello");
    this.datosPropietarioLblNumIdentificacion.Visible = true;
    this.datosPropietariotxtNumIdentificacion.Visible = true;
}
```

each drop has its own method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {               
        this.datosPropietarioLblNumIdentificacion.Visible = false;
        this.datosPropietariotxtNumIdentificacion.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Tipo de Identificación"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="droplistTipoIdentificacionDatosPropietario"
            runat="server" 
            Width="100%" 
            Height="30px"
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="droplistTipoIdentificacionDatosPropietario_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Cédula Identidad" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Cédula de Residencia" Value="R"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Cédula Jurídica" Value="J"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pasaporte" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind call

```
protected void droplistTipoIdentificacionDatosPropietario_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hola");
    this.datosPropietarioLblNumIdentificacion.Visible = true;
    this.datosPropietariotxtNumIdentificacion.Visible = true;
}
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="grid3">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Provincia"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="droplistProvincia" 
                AutoPostBack="true" onchange="testProvincia"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="droplistProvincia_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                Width="100%" runat="server" Height="30px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Seleccione"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Cantón"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="droplistCanton" CssClass="item15" 
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="droplistCanton_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                Width="100%" runat="server" Height="30px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Seleccione"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item16" Text="Distrito"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="droplistDistrito"
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="droplistDistrito_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                CssClass="item17"  runat="server" Height="30px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Seleccione"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a copy/paste issue; sometimes copy/paste will not execute code. Try deleting the code-behind methods from each dropdown and re-adding them.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="droplistProvincia" 
    AutoPostBack="true" onchange="testProvincia"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="droplistProvincia_SelectedIndexChanged" <- delete this
    Width="100%" runat="server" Height="30px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Seleccione"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Delete the line as shown above, and also delete the code-behind. Re-add by double-clicking the dropdown list.

Hope that helps. It's hard to tell what the problem is from your question.